# Unevaluated List as part of a function

Tags: list-manipulation, function-construction, hold

```
  Is there a solution?

  (* after the suggestions of nice people comes here   
   the whole story: *)

mengeA = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "A", "Q", "P", "B", "E", "F", "G", "H", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "A", "F", "M", "S", "E", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y",  "Z"};



spMengeA = {"A", "C", "E", "K", "M", "N", "O", "Q", "S","U", "W", "Y"};


   ClearAll[takeFollowingMembersFrom];
   takeFollowingMembersFrom[menge_List, firstElem_String, 
   numberOfElemTotal_Integer] := 
   Module[{a0, a1, a2, a3, allPos, myFun, pos},
   ClearAll[myFun];
   SetAttributes[myFun, HoldFirst];
   myFun[li_, item_String] := 
   MemberQ[Symbol["sp" ~~ Capitalize@SymbolName[Unevaluated@li]], 
   item];

  pos = DeleteDuplicates[
  Flatten[Position[menge, #] & /@ 
   Select[menge, 
    StringMatchQ[#, firstElem] && myFun[menge, #] &]]]; 
  allPos = {{#}} & /@ pos; 
  a1 = Extract[menge, 
   Flatten[FoldList[Plus, #, Table[1, numberOfElemTotal - 1]], 
    1]] & /@ allPos];

   takeFollowingMembersFrom[mengeA, "A", 3]

  (*and I want to get:  {{"A","B","C"},{"A","Q","P"},{"A","F","M"}} *)
```

Comment: You’d need to set a `Hold` attribute (perhaps `HoldFirst`) for your function `myFun`. You can use [`SetAttributes`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetAttributes.html).

Answer (score 1):

```
ClearAll[myFun]
SetAttributes[myFun, HoldFirst]
myFun[li_, item_String] :=
 MemberQ[
   Symbol["sp" ~~ Capitalize@SymbolName[Unevaluated@li]],
   item
 ]   

myFun[mengeA, "K"]           (* Out: True  *)
myFun[mengeA, "B"]           (* Out: False *)
```

Comment: Unfortunately the suggestion won't work, because the element "K" has to be able to change to for example "T" oder "W" as part of an other function.

Comment: @Andreas See the edit.

Answer (score 0):

With the pattern `li_List`, evaluation happens and that should be avoided to achieve what you are doing.

Next, to prevent `mengeA` getting evaluated before `myFun1` sees it we need to either:

A) wrap it in `Unevaluated` as below
or

B) `myFun1` needs to have the `HoldAll` or `HoldFirst` attribute as suggested by MarcoB.

```
ClearAll[myFun1]
myFun1 := ToExpression@StringJoin["sp", Capitalize@ToString@Unevaluated@#]&

MemberQ[myFun1[Unevaluated@mengeA], "K"]

(* True *)
```

Comment: 1) Your approach requires the user to add `Unevaluated` each time the function is called, which is time-consuming and error-prone; also, since you would never call this function without the `Unevaluated`, it should really be included inside its definition. 2) Since you defined `myFun` as a pure function, you do not need to use `SetDelayed` to force the re-evaluation of the definition at each call; `Set` would do.

Comment: @MarcoB Fair points.  I am just suggesting *a* solution.

Comment: Unfortunately the suggestion won't work, because the element "K" has to be able to change to for example "T" oder "W" as part of an other function.